# Link to chrome://chrome/extensions from extension options page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using the chrome bootstrap styles (see http://roykolak.github.com/chrome-bootstrap/)  to build my options page. Now I'd like to have a link back to chrome://chrome/extensions in the left-sidebar menu, but clicking on it returns an error in the console: `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://chrome/extensions`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can open this with `chrome.tabs.update`, [you don't need the tabs permission for this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#manifest).

**options.html**

```
<script src="options.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="test">test</a>
```

**options.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.update({ url: 'chrome://chrome/extensions' });
    });
});
```