# Anchor link to Firefox about:config?

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, anchor, uninstallation

As [the single way I found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Apps_for_Android#Uninstalling_an_app) to uninstall a webapp is to go to the about:apps page, I wanted to code the following:

```
 <p>To uninstall the webapp, please go to 
 <a href="about:apps">about:apps</a></p>
```

But, on Firefox v21 it does not open any page.

Then, I failed also using about:config.

```
 <a href="about:config">about:config</a>
```

Therefore I wonder whether it is possible to provide a hypertext link to the about:apps or about:config... What are your advices about this issue?

---

**EDIT:** `document.location` does not help

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//document.location = 'http://www.mozilla.org';
// -> OK 

  document.location = 'about:config';
  // -> Error: Access to 'about:config' from script denied
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `document.location` with Javascript?

Comment: I have not tried yet using JavaScript. Thanks for the idea, I will try later and tell you if this fix my issue. Thank you very much. Cheers

Comment: You probably found it already, but I also found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.webapps/ySNNMUlE70c ... maybe it helps...

Comment: `document.location` does not work. Thanks @Joum for the link. I have found the same thread on mail-archive.com (http://www.mail-archive.com/dev-webapps@lists.mozilla.org/msg00578.html)... I will ask another question for that... Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are simple not allowed to insert a link to a local resource due to security issues.

Comment: I think so, but I have not found an official explanation of Mozilla... Please can you provide a reference for what you say? I would appreciate a lot ;-) Cheers

Comment: If you do this for example:  
`<a href="#" onclick="document.location.href='chrome://chrome/'">click</a>`
and try it in the browser it comes up with an error:
"Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://chrome/".

Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125616/link-to-chrome-chrome-extensions-from-extension-options-page is a post about how you might do it but when I tried it, it still didn't work.