# uninstall a webapp on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, uninstallation, mozapps

To uninstall a webapp, [Mozilla says to go to about:apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Apps_for_Android#Uninstalling_an_app). Therefore, I [asked about anchor link to Firefox about:config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018696). But it seems impossible to go to `about:config` (or `about:apps`) from a web page.

Then, [Joum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24098) advised to use `navigator.mozApps.mgmg.uninstall()` as [indicated by Mathieu Rochette](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev-webapps@lists.mozilla.org/msg00578.html).

**But how to use `navigator.mozApps.mgmg.uninstall()` within a web page?** 
**What are the other ways to uninstall a webapp on Firefox?**

Comment: After thinking about this for a while, there shouldn't be a straightforward way to do this. Think about this: a link to `about:config` wouldn't be interpreted in the same way by all browsers - so in a webapp it can't be a solution because you want it to be cross-browser compatible. More, the method my Mathieu Rochette specifficaly targets local installs (_HTML5 offline app_ as he stated). Does your app fall in that category?

Comment: Yes @Joum, my webapp is in that category. You can see my source code at http://www.lmap.org/index_v3.html. I have tried the `unistall()` but while debugging on Firebug I saw this function was not (yet?) implemented on Firefox v22 (release) and v23 (beta). I will try later on Aurora (Firefox v24). Have fun. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I'm running Firefox on Linux, I'd like to share my solution but it might not work on Windows or other platforms.

Firefox creates a .directory for each web app in your home, for example:

```
~/.http\;robnyman.github.com
```

You can run

```
~/.http\;robnyman.github.com/webapprt-stub -remove
```

to remove that app. And you will get a notification that the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 2):

To manually ***un***install a webapp on *Firefox for Android*, you can go to `about:apps`.

Unfortunately, `about:apps` is not yet available on *Firefox for Desktop*.

Using Aurora (Firefox v24) and Firebug, I retrieved the latest API of `navigator.mozApps`:

```
navigator.mozApps [xpconnect wrapped mozIDOMApplicationRegistry]
|
+-- QueryInterface()
|
+-- checkInstalled()
|
+-- getInstalled()
|
+-- getSelf()
|
+-- install()
|
+-- __proto__ [xpconnect wrapped native prototype] 
    |
    +-- QueryInterface()
    |
    +-- checkInstalled()
    |
    +-- getInstalled()
    |
    +-- getSelf()
    |
    +-- install()
```

Therefore, there is no `uninstall()` function...

In fact, the main issue is to avoid a webapp to uninstall another webapp (i.e. a website uninstalling webapps from another website). I think this is something Mozilla is working on... let's see on further versions...

Comment: `about:apps` is still not available on Firefox 38 Linux