# how to create a link element tag to about:config?

Tags: python, html, selenium, firefox

I tried,

```
<a href="about:config">setup</a>
```

element just shows up on the Firefox browser, but cannot open it (clicking won't work) or open it in a new tab.

Is there a way to create a link element to open up `about:config` page in Firefox using just HTML?

According to this it's imposible [Anchor link to Firefox about:config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018696/anchor-link-to-firefox-aboutconfig)
right?

But, how about in Selenium with geckodriver?

Comment: can you remove the flag? so, python or selenium user can contribute to this. @JJJ

Answer (score 1):

I think this question answers your question: [Anchor link to Firefox about:config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018696/anchor-link-to-firefox-aboutconfig). Give it a try. Basically, you are not allowed to reference a local resource due to security issues (like the post says).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's [not possible due to security concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018696/anchor-link-to-firefox-aboutconfig).

I'm not sure how useful this is, but if you can get the user to create a bookmark, it will work from a bookmark.